# How to implement Request function on scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from string import join
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.crawl import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from article.items import ArticleItem

class ArticleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "article"
    allowed_domains = ["http://joongang.joins.com"]
    j_classifications = ['politics','money','society','culture']

    start_urls = ["http://news.joins.com/%s" % classification for 
    classification in j_classifications]

def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    urls = sel.xpath('//div[@class="bd"]/ul/li/strong')
    items = []         
    for url in urls:
        item = ArticleItem()
        item['url'] = url.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)

    request =  Request(items['url'], callback=self.parse_item2)
    request.meta['item'] = items     
    return request

def parse_item2(self,response):
    item = response.meta['item'] 
    sel = Selector(response)
    articles = sel.xpath('//div[@id=article_body]')
    for article in articles:
        item['article'] = article.xpath('text()').extract()
        items.append(item)

    return item
```

This code for article scrap. I've been used the scrapy.
The parse_item method is implemented for article's url which sent to parse_item2 using request function. But this code don't work. Item class did implement to url = Field(), article = Field(). How can i solve this problem. 
PS The web tag is exact. I did test that at scrapy shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your code in the line:

```
request =  Request(items['url'], callback=self.parse_item2)
```

`items` is a list of `item` object. So it will raise a TypeError. You can do it with a second for loop,

```
for itm in items:
    request =  Request(itm['url'], callback=self.parse_item2)
    request.meta['item'] = items     
    yield request
```

Or yield a request from the first for loop,

```
for url in urls:
    item = ArticleItem()
    item['url'] = url.xpath('a/@href').extract()
    request =  Request(items['url'], callback=self.parse_item2)
    request.meta['item'] = items
    yield request
```